# How to Get Counter Variable to Increment Properly in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, variables, scope

I'm having an issue that in testing, it is not working out. My code is for a button that checks whether or not a correct answer has been input. If the answer is correct, there's a message in the label; conversely, there's a message if it's wrong.

What I have in mind is to have a variable that checks if a wrong input has been entered "3 times" then have my code show that in the label. Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub btnAnswer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAnswer.Click

    'Setup count variable to monitor wrong answer count.
    Dim CounterWrong As Integer = 1

    If (txtSpell.Text = "Bicycle") And (CounterVar = 0) Then
        lblAnsResult.Text = "Correct!"
        lblAnsResult.Show()
        btnNext.Focus()

    ElseIf (txtSpell.Text = "Table") And (CounterVar = 1) Then
        lblAnsResult.Text = "Correct!"
        lblAnsResult.Show()
        btnNext.Focus()

    ElseIf (txtSpell.Text = "Television") And (CounterVar = 2) Then
        lblAnsResult.Text = "Correct!"
        lblAnsResult.Show()
        btnNext.Focus()

    Else
        CounterWrong += 1
        txtSpell.Text = String.Empty
        lblAnsResult.Text = "Wrong! Try Again..."
        lblAnsResult.Show()
        txtSpell.Text = Focus()

    End If

    While CounterWrong < 3
        CounterWrong += 1

        If CounterWrong = 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show(CounterWrong)
        End If
    End While

End Sub
```

I tried to setup my little `While` loop to see if my `CounterWrong` variable is incrementing properly, but I can't think of how to set it up. I know each time I click the button, `CounterWrong` is being set back to 1. Can someone set me in the right direction here? Thanks.

Comment: Tip: use `AndAlso` instead of `And` to test conditions; it short-circuits.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: you mean as such: `If (txtSpell.Text = "Bicycle") AndAlso (CounterVar = 0)`?

Comment: Yep! Generally, use `And` for bitwise operations, and `AndAlso` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change the counter to a VB 'Static' variable:

```
Static CounterWrong As Integer = 0
```

or use a class-level field:

```
Private CounterWrong As Integer = 0
```

VB 'Static' variables maintain state between method calls (C++ has a similar feature).
Many would regard using a field as better practice.

I also changed them to be '0' initially - I think this makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, I agree on the field variable, and I tried that before, but it  produced the same results - I have another similarly declared field variable in the program. I will try it again to see if it works, or just declare the `Static` inside the `btnAnswer` Sub.

Comment: I set it up as Private and it worked. Funny, as I said I did this before, but was working on two other projects and probably had my wires crossed! Lol. Either way, you get the credit anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could declare the variable on the form instead:

```
Public Class frmTest

    'Setup count variable to monitor wrong answer count.
    Dim CounterWrong As Integer = 1


    Private Sub btnAnswer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAnswer.Click

        If (txtSpell.Text = "Bicycle") And (CounterVar = 0) Then
            lblAnsResult.Text = "Correct!"
            lblAnsResult.Show()
            btnNext.Focus()

        ElseIf (txtSpell.Text = "Table") And (CounterVar = 1) Then
            lblAnsResult.Text = "Correct!"
            lblAnsResult.Show()
            btnNext.Focus()

        ElseIf (txtSpell.Text = "Television") And (CounterVar = 2) Then
            lblAnsResult.Text = "Correct!"
            lblAnsResult.Show()
            btnNext.Focus()

        Else
            CounterWrong += 1
            txtSpell.Text = String.Empty
            lblAnsResult.Text = "Wrong! Try Again..."
            lblAnsResult.Show()
            txtSpell.Text = Focus()

        End If

        If CounterWrong = 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show(CounterWrong)
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```